# Weight of a bag of crisps follows a normal law. Should calculating the probability that one weighs < 140 g take care if bags are in samples?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, sample

I'm stuck at an exercise question.

A bag of crisps has a weight that follows $X \sim N(m=150\ \rm g, \sigma=20\ \rm g)$

we are taking samples of 15 bags of crisps
whose have for mean weight $\overline{X} \sim N(m=150\ \rm g, \sigma=5.164\ \rm g)$

The question I am asked by a book is:
*What's the probability that a bag of crisps weighs less than 140 g?*

What shall I understand and do here?

1. Draw the $N(m=150\ \rm g, \sigma=20\ \rm g)$, the weight of a bag of crisps whether it is in a sample or not, on a paper or calculate when $X \leq 140\ \rm g$?
2. Shall I take care that the question could be understood as:

- *What's the probability that **one** (and only one) bag of crisps weighs less than 140 g?*
  Then, I should take in account that we are considering a sample of 15 bags of crisps, meaning that I am doing 15 draws, and I am expecting to follow an Binomial law giving us one success only?
- or the opposite: **up to all** bags could weigh less than 140 g, and I would be looking for one success or more?

3. Something else? I don't think $\overline{X} \sim N(m=150\ \rm g, \sigma=5.164\ \rm g)$ could be involved, here. But maybe a proportion?

The expected result is 0.3086 says my book. But I'm bit lost, you see.
Can you help me?

Comment: Another interpretation--by far the more interesting one, because it's the only one not already addressed in other threads--is that this question asks for the chance that *there exists at least one bag under 140 g. within a sample of weight $w.$*  The answer will depend on $w.$

Comment: It's difficult to understand why they are so much work to mark as "not accepting answers" a question that has received its answers quickly, already. Whose question and answer have been upvoted, accepted, and the whole question has fulfilled its goals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that the sample has nothing to do with this question.

The easy way to answer the question is to find a normal distribution calculator like this: https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1180573188

There you can plug in the X (140 g) along with information of the distribution (150 g, 20 g) and it will tell you that the lower cumulative P (The probability of finding a bag 140 g or lower) is about 0.309.

---

The trickier way (but easier without specifically a normal distribution calculator) is to "standardise" the measurement you have. You do this by first subtracting the mean and then dividing by the standard deviation. So to standardise your 140 g you would compute (140-150)/20 = -0.5.

Then you can look up this standardised value in a z table like this: https://www.ztable.net/

It will also tell you the probability is 0.309.

Comment: When I was a student, the trickier way was the only way.